# VBA copy self to other location

Tags: vba, excel, directory, copy-paste

I have an Excel-Macro in VBA in which I want to copy the file from where the macro is executed into another location.

I tried it like this

```
Call FileCopy(currentDir & "\" & Filename, _
otherDir & "\" & Filename)
```

But I get an `Access restricted` Exception, although I have full access to all of the directories involved. Is it because I'm trying to "copy myself"? Is this possible? If not, could I build a workaround?

Comment: Hello, it is also possible that you can't read the source file.

Comment: How do you create the folder... Please show us your code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs otherDir & "Test1"
```

or

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs otherDir & "Test2"
```

ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook which contains the macro you are running...

**Update** :  This should work for you to create a folder...

Make sure you add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" under Tools -> references.

```
 Dim fso As FileSystemObject
 Set fso = New FileSystemObject
 fso.CreateFolder ("C:\test\test2")
 ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "c:\test\test2\ttt.xlsm"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using FileCopy didnt work for me either but using CopyFile from FileSystemObject seems to work.

First you will need to add a Reference (Menu: Tools->References) to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime and then use the FileSystemObject

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

fso.CopyFile currentDir & "\" & Filename, otherDir & "\" & Filename, True
''the last parameter decides weather or not you want to overwrite existing files

Set fso = Nothing
```

Alternative: Save the document at the new destination and then save it back.

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs otherDir & "\" & Filename
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs currentDir & "\" & Filename
```

Comment: I tried the second method, but now I'm getting "Access to the locked directory "xx" not possible" - Is it because my macro creates this directory itself? Maybe it's locked because of this? How can I set folders free after I created them?

Comment: I use `CreateFolder` of a `FileSystemObject` - but that wasn't the problem after all. I noticed that the folder I created already existed from another source and therefore was locked. After I deleted it and my macro created it as a new one, the saving worked fine. Thanks for the help!